# Google Analytics Addon Multiple Segments

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to apply two segments to my google analytics report with the addon on google sheets.

I'm trying to segment new users who did not vist /dashboards/

My query is below

`users::condition::ga:pagePath!@/dashboards/::ga:userType=@New`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try escaping slash before and after /dashboards/?
I would also try exact match rather than string match for dashboards if it is your only page to be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have found the answer to this by now now, however this would work

```
users::condition::!ga:pagePath!@/dashboards/;condition::ga:userType=@New
```